# OctoberCMS: What are the difference between slugs and id

Tags: javascript, html, css, content-management-system, octobercms

Can someone explain to me why should I use slugs/id instead of the other one? Is there any difference?

Answer (score 2):

Its more like **`SEO thing`**,

your url

```
// url preset : /product/:id
http://awesomewebsite.com/product/12


// url preset : /product/:product-slug
http://awesomewebsite.com/product/popular-product
```

> **Now in google or any search engine** its **more chance** to get your **product link as result** if you use `product-slug` instead of `id`

user will search like `popular product` and it can lead to your link

> But if you **use id** user will **never going to search like `12`**

So, its for SEO purpose, if your site do not need SEO in anyway you can use id there is no issue in that, internally both works same you use `id` to fetch record or you can use `slug` to fetch record.

if you have any doubt please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you definitely want to have an id in your database table, though slugs are optional and typically used to make URLs look pretty. For example, if you defined your page url like this: `url = "/product/:product_id"`, then your url that users would see would be something like: `https://yourdomain.tld/product/1925`

On the other hand, if you used a slug, like this: `url = "/product/:product_slug"`, then your url that users would see would be something nicer like: `https://yourdomain.tld/product/my-fancy-gadget`